# Perfect Indicative Active and 1 John 1:10

Tags: greek

1 John 1:10

> If we say, "We have not sinned," we make him a liar, and his word is not in us.

The verb ἡμαρτήκαμεν is a **perfect indicative active** of the verb 'to sin' here and same author, different context but the same verbal tense in [John 17:9](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/john/17-9.htm) with δέδωκάς, which means to give.

[1 John 1:10](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/1_john/1-10.htm)

If we take a principle of hermeneutics about usage and context, is 1 John 1:10 talking about the sin the person had before Christ? The **perfect indicative active** verb in John 17 to give the people to Jesus wasn't ongoing at that moment. He had just had an intimate time (John 13-16) before praying in John 17 and then he would be given up to be crucified. No one was joining the group of Jesus' disciples during that time. Otherwise, John 17:9 would say "those whom you have given to me and are giving to me now".

So, it would be easy to conclude from this that 1 John 1:10 (have not sinned) is talking about before Christ. John was not saying "If we should say that we have not sinned and are not sinning now..."

The fact John doesn't say in 1 John 1:10, 'If we say we have never and will never sin again', which is frequently interpreted for this verse, then understanding this tense changes the reading. Doesn't it? Is he not talking about a past lifetime, before meeting Christ?

Comment: I wish I could understand what question you are asking and thus understand your problem!!  John 17 is talking about the disciples that Jesus already had.  What is difficult about that?

Comment: Hey Dottard! The question is about the use of the same tense and how different interpretations say the John 17:9 makes sense Jesus already had disciples but that 1 John 1:10 says that means we HAD BEEN sinning and still ARE sinning. Not about sinless perfection, since that is addressed in 1 John 1:8.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Christ. Its a gen truth about concealing sins. Prov 28.13 He who conceals his sins doesn't prosper, but whoever confesses and renounces them finds mercy.

Comment: Nobody can interpret the verse like that, "have been sinning" when the verse only talks about hiding past sins at the moment. It is not about habitual practice of sinning but any sin which we have committed.

Answer (score 0):

After more research, I believe it's a correct assessment to accept, "Action occurred and was completed in the past, but its effect are felt in the present," as a clear way of how the verb in 1 John 1:10 should be seen and handled.

This means it is not possible to explain any sort of overt or even implied reasoning within 1 John 1:10 of "sinning every day in word, thought, and action". This verse simply points to the fact that once Christ came into our lives, we have readily already admitted and still readily admit our lives were contrary to God's design prior to our submission of trust in Christ.

However, after seeing more examples within the Greek text throughout the New Testament and after hearing more about this same verse last night, I can see also that as a follower of Christ we are continuing to leave our sins behind us and to admit otherwise (as seen in 1 John 1:10) is deception. So, **whether because I left my sinful life behind when I first turned to Jesus or I do the same each day now**, the perfect indicative active gives great illumination to this fact.

However, I'm still especially willing to hear more from anyone with more insight into this verse, especially as it applies to the perfect indicative active in the ancient Greek language.

[Explanation of Perfect Indicative Active](https://gknt.org/class/notes/bbg-25-perfect-indicative)

Comment: Ask and answer on the same day? Are you looking for an answer or want to share your own insight?

Comment: Looking for an answer. You believe in being fair? I'm still listening.